# MongoDB Aggregate - How do I search between arrays within collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a data structure similar to this:

```
users:
[
  {
    userID: 46,
    rockSets: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    rockPostings: [ 1, 2 ]
  },
  {
    userID: 53,
    rockSets: [ 4, 5 ],
    rockPostings: [ 3 ]
  }  
]

rock_sets:
[
  {
    rockSetID: 1,
    userID: 46,
    active: true,
    rocks: [ 'quartz', 'agate' ]
  },
  {
    rockSetID: 2,
    userID: 46,
    active: true,
    rocks: [ 'sodalite', 'onyx', 'amethyst' ]
  },
  {
    rockSetID: 3,
    userID: 46,
    active: true,
    rocks: [ 'fancy jasper', 'blue lace agate' ]
  },
  {
    rockSetID: 4,
    userID: 53,
    active: true,
    rocks: [ 'aquamarine', 'tiger eye' ]
  },
  {
    rockSetID: 5,
    userID: 53,
    active: true,
    rocks: [ 'unakite', 'amethyst' ]
  }
]

rock_postings:
[
  {
    rockPostingID: 1,
    userID: 46,
    active: true,
    requiredRocks: [ 'aquamarine', 'red jasper' ]
  }
  {
    rockPostingID: 2,
    userID: 46,
    active: true,
    requiredRocks: [ 'aventurine' ]
  } 
  {
    rockPostingID: 3,
    userID: 53,
    active: true,
    requiredRocks: [ 'fancy jasper', 'rose quartz' ]
  }  
]
```

The user publicly lists which `rockSets` they have and can also create `rockPostings` to let other users know which `rocks` they are seeking. If I login as user `46`, I'd like to know which users have postings with rocks from my sets so I may contact them for inquiry (and vice-versa). Here's my code so far:

```
router.get('/:id/potentialclients', function(req, res) {
  var rockSets = req.db.get('rock_sets');
  var rockPostings = req.db.get('rock_postings');

  rockSets.col.aggregate([
      { $match: { 
        $and: [
          { userID: req.params.id },
          { active: true }
        ]}},
      { $unwind: '$rocks' }
    ], function(err, userRockSets) {
      rockPostings.col.aggregate([ 
          { $match: { active: true }},
          { $unwind: '$requiredRocks' },
          { $lookup: {
            from: userRockSets, // Issue #1
            localField: 'requiredRocks', // Issue #2
            foreignField: 'rocks',
            as: 'potentialClients'
          }}
        ], function(err, data) {
          res.json(data);
        })
    });
});
```

First, I perform an aggregate on the `rockSets` collection to unwind the user's `rocks` and pass it to `userRockSets`. Then, I perform a second aggregate on the `rockPostings` collection in attempt to join it to `userRockSets`. I know of at least 2 issues with the code above and I've commented their location. Issue #1 does not work because `from` expects a DB collection name string. Issue #2 isn't right because it's not using the unwound `requiredRocks` collection. `foreignField` also isn't right because the `from` is not capturing the right collection. I'm trying to achieve something like this as a result of hitting the above endpoint with user 46:

```
[
  {
    userID: 46,
    potentialClientID: 53,
    rockSetID: 3,
    rockPostingID: 3,
    matchedRocks: [ 'fancy jasper' ]
  }
]
```

... and any other rock postings that match. The end-goal is also to implement a filter to adjust how many rocks must match between collections before postings are returned - the current implementation will only look for 1. I've looked at `$redact` and am thinking it might be useful for what I'm trying to do, I just haven't seen where I would use it.